# Jenkins Testrunner run SOAPUI Tests

Tags: jenkins, soapui, test-runner

I have 1 Jenkins slave for running SOAPUI tests. (I didn't set that slave) In Jenkins this projects is set to run using "Execute Windows batch command:"
[image]

```
testrunner -s"All_tests" "D:\Jenkins\SoapUI_scripts\project.xml"
```

It works good on that Jenkins slave, but I wanted to add another Jenkins slave for SOAPUI test cases. But same windows batch command doesn't work on that new machine.

I get this message in Jenkins console output on machine:

```
'testrunner' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is there anything what I have to set on that machine to make this work?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I have installed SoapUI on both slaves.

**EDIT 2:**
In Jenkins I have set remote root directory for all Jenkins slaves to D:\Jenkins\  (because of diferent scripts).
If I set PATH for SoapUI (C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin) in batch command it works.
On the old slave I can execute just this command in any folder and it works:

```
testrunner -s"All_tests" "D:\Jenkins\SoapUI_scripts\project.xml"
```

Just on the new slave I need to execute batch command just from the SoapUI installation PATH.

I can't setup path in that batch command, because SoapUI is installed in different folders on slaves.

**LAST EDIT:**
In our company we have limited user accounts. So I had to give this task to administrator. He setup something on slave and now it works same on both slaves. I don't know what he did, because in system variables there isn't 'testrunner folder'.

Now I can run it like this on both slaves:

```
testrunner -s"Suite_Name" "D:\Jenkins\SoapUI_scripts\Project_Name.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

Testrunner is the BAT file, that you run, when you want to run a SoapUI testsuite from a commandline. The error shows, that it can't be found.

My guess is that you have SoapUI installed on one client/slave, but not the other.

Either that, or the local PATH has not been updated to include the SoapUI installation path.

Comment: I have installed SoapUI on both slaves. I will try to look at the PATH

Answer (score 1):

You should include full absolute path of `testrunner.bat` file as well as `testsuite.xml` in order to run it successfully. Something like this :

```
<--full-directory-path-->testrunner.bat "<--name-of-your-testsuitefile.xml-->"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try setting PATH for SOAP UI again in the execute batch and check.

Comment: It works If I set PATH for SoapUI (C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin) in batch . In Jenkins I have set remote root directory for all Jenkins slaves to D:\Jenkins\  (because of different scripts). On the old slave I can call testrunner from any folder and it works. Just on the new slave I need to call testrunner just from the SoapUI installation PATH. I want to call testrunner from any folder on both slaves.

Comment: If i understood differently please ignore. As a workaround if you set PATH again for SOAP UI in the beginning of execute batch you can call testrunner from any folder inside that.